# How do upload or drag and drop image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I want to make drag and drop upload. User drops the files on text-area, and when he clicks on the div area and select the pic to the browser after selecting the pic then automatically the uploading progress bar start and sent the picture to the server side through java-script, PHP, jQuery or Ajax unfortunately does not know how its can done because I don't know about these language i'm new in this field can some one help me and tell me briefly about this

here is my code(only important things , I removed the other things to make code look smaller) but at the end i will include my all code in **snippet** which you can understand easily

```
`<div class="imgbob-home-modal">`
<div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modal-full-width" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-width modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">
     <span>JPEG JPG PNG GIF</span>
     <span> - </span>
     <span>Max 10 MB</span>
     </h5>
  <span class="float-right imgbob-reset-button d-none">
   <div class="upload-more" id="imgbob-upload-clickable">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
     <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
     <path d="M7 18a4.6 4.4 0 0 1 0 -9a5 4.5 0 0 1 11 2h1a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7h-1" />
     <polyline points="9 15 12 12 15 15" />
     <line x1="12" y1="12" x2="12" y2="21" />
    </svg>
    Upload more
   </div>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-here" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="imgbob-main-upload-section">
   <div id="upload-process">
    <div id="imgbob-uploader-box" class="imgbob-uploader-box">
     <div id="imgbob-upload-clickable" class="imgbob-uploder-place" >
      <div class="imgbob-upload-icon">
       <img class="img-responsivee" src="https://imgbob.com/images/sections/upload.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Drag and drop or <span>browse</span> images here to upload</h3>
      <p>You can upload 5 images in one time.</p>
      <p><span>Max Filesize. 10 MB(s)</span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uploaded-success row" id="imgbob-preview-uploads"></div>
    <div>
     <div id="imgbob-drop-template" class="col-lg-4 mb-3 m-auto imgbob-uploader-area d-none">
      <div class="imgbob-card fade-in">
       <span class="success-icon-box d-none fade-in">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" /><path d="M5 12l5 5l10 -10" /></svg>
       </span>
       <span class="error-icon-box d-none fade-in">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" /><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18" /><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18" /></svg>
       </span>
       <div class="remove-icon">
        <i data-dz-remove class="fa fa-remove"></i>
       </div>
       <img data-dz-thumbnail class="imgbob-upload-icon">
       <div class="imgbob-images-upload">
        <div class="imgbob-images-name" data-dz-name></div>
        <div class="imgbob-uploder-progress">
         <div class="alert alert-danger alert-error d-none" role="alert"></div>
         <textarea readonly class="form-control success-input d-none" rows="2"></textarea>
         <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-view success-button d-none">View image</a>
         <div class="progress upload-progress">
          <div data-dz-uploadprogress class="progress-bar bg-primary progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">Uploading...</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```

**and now i include my all code in snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#206bc4">
   <meta name="description" content="Upload images, Upload files, Free image hosting and sharing service, upload pictures, photo host, images to forums, Free images upload,">
   <meta name="keywords" content="free image hosting, image uploader, forum image hosting, image upload mod, image host, photo sharing, upload pictures, upload images, upload files, share images">
   <meta property="og:title" content="Upload and share your images." />
   <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Imgbob" />
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://imgbob.com" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="https://imgbob.com/images/main/logo.png" />
   <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
   <meta name="twitter:description" content="Upload images, Upload files, Free image hosting and sharing service, upload pictures, photo host, images to forums, Free images upload,">
   <meta name="twitter:title" content="Imgbob — Upload and share your images.">
   <meta name="twitter:site" content="https://imgbob.com">
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="NU6cJj2GtY8VgE1QZ35qsA1EomEDLPMDqJPiyvzA">
   <title>Ackta — Upload and share your images.</title>
   <link href="ackta-fav.png" rel="shortcut icon">
   <link href="ackta-fav.png" type="image/png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://imgbob.com/images/main/favicon.ico" sizes="180x180">
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/libs/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/fontawesome/font-awesome-animation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/libs/dropzone/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/css/app-vendors.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://imgbob.com/assets/css/ibob.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8320136810729992" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="imgbob_home_body">
   <script>
         "use strict";
           const SITE_URL= "https://imgbob.com";
           const MAX_FILES= 5;
           const MAX_SIZE = 10;
           const BIG_FILES_DETECTED = "This File Type not Allowed."; 
   </script>
   <header class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light d-print-none ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-menu">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-autodark d-none-navbar-horizontal  me-md-3 ">
      <a href="userhome.php">
       <img src="logo3.png" width="110" height="32" alt="Imgbob" class="navbar-brand-image">
      </a>
     </h1>
     <div class="navbar-nav flex-row order-md-last">
      <li class="nav-item pe-0 pe-md-2 d-mobile-none">
       <a href="headerfile.php" class="btn">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
         <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
         <path d="M14 8v-2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2h-7a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-2" />
         <path d="M20 12h-13l3 -3m0 6l-3 -3" />
        </svg>
        Sign in
       </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-mobile-none">
       <a href="signup.php" class="btn btn-primary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
         <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
         <circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4" />
         <path d="M3 21v-2a4 4 0 0 1 4 -4h4a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v2" />
         <path d="M16 11h6m-3 -3v6" />
        </svg>
        Create account
       </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item pe-1 d-md-none mobile-icon">
       <a href="headerfile.php">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
         <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
         <path d="M14 8v-2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2h-7a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-2" />
         <path d="M20 12h-13l3 -3m0 6l-3 -3" />
        </svg>
       </a>
      </li>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-md-first" id="navbar-menu">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row flex-fill align-items-stretch align-items-md-center">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item  active ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="userhome.php">
          <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
            <polyline points="5 12 3 12 12 3 21 12 19 12" />
            <path d="M5 12v7a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-7" />
            <path d="M9 21v-6a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v6" />
           </svg>
          </span>
          <span class="nav-link-title">Home</span>
         </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#navbar-third" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
            <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12.01" y2="8" />
            <polyline points="11 12 12 12 12 16 13 16" />
           </svg>
          </span>
          <span class="nav-link-title d-lg-none d-xl-inline-block">About</span>
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item  " href="userdeleting.php">Deleting Account</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item  " href="userprivacy.php">Privacy policy</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item  " href="userterm.php">Terms of use</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item  " href="usercontact.php">Contact Us</a>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#modal-full-width" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-full-width">
          <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
            <path d="M7 18a4.6 4.4 0 0 1 0 -9a5 4.5 0 0 1 11 2h1a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7h-1" />
            <polyline points="9 15 12 12 15 15" />
            <line x1="12" y1="12" x2="12" y2="21" />
           </svg>
          </span>
          <span class="nav-link-title d-lg-none d-xl-inline-block">Upload</span>
         </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <div class="imgbob-drag-zone" id="imgbob-drag-zone">
    <div class="ibobdrag imgbob-drag-zone-place">
     <div class="imgbob-home-modal">
      <div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modal-full-width" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-width modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">
           <span>JPEG JPG PNG GIF</span>
           <span> - </span>
           <span>Max 10 MB</span>
          </h5>
          <span class="float-right imgbob-reset-button d-none">
           <div class="upload-more" id="imgbob-upload-clickable">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
             <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
             <path d="M7 18a4.6 4.4 0 0 1 0 -9a5 4.5 0 0 1 11 2h1a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7h-1" />
             <polyline points="9 15 12 12 15 15" />
             <line x1="12" y1="12" x2="12" y2="21" />
            </svg>
            Upload more
           </div>
          </span>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-here" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="imgbob-main-upload-section">
           <div id="upload-process">
            <div id="imgbob-uploader-box" class="imgbob-uploader-box">
             <div id="imgbob-upload-clickable" class="imgbob-uploder-place" >
              <div class="imgbob-upload-icon">
               <img class="img-responsivee" src="https://imgbob.com/images/sections/upload.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              <h3>Drag and drop or <span>browse</span> images here to upload</h3>
              <p>You can upload 5 images in one time.</p>
              <p><span>Max Filesize. 10 MB(s)</span></p>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uploaded-success row" id="imgbob-preview-uploads"></div>
            <div>
             <div id="imgbob-drop-template" class="col-lg-4 mb-3 m-auto imgbob-uploader-area d-none">
              <div class="imgbob-card fade-in">
               <span class="success-icon-box d-none fade-in">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" /><path d="M5 12l5 5l10 -10" /></svg>
               </span>
               <span class="error-icon-box d-none fade-in">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" /><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18" /><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18" /></svg>
               </span>
               <div class="remove-icon">
                <i data-dz-remove class="fa fa-remove"></i>
               </div>
               <img data-dz-thumbnail class="imgbob-upload-icon">
               <div class="imgbob-images-upload">
                <div class="imgbob-images-name" data-dz-name></div>
               <!-- <div class="imgbob-uploder-progress">
                 <div class="alert alert-danger alert-error d-none" role="alert"></div>
                 <textarea readonly class="form-control success-input d-none" rows="2"></textarea>
                 <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-view success-button d-none">View image</a>
                 <div class="progress upload-progress">
                  <div data-dz-uploadprogress class="progress-bar bg-primary progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">Uploading...</div>
                 </div>
                </div>-->
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="topA container">
      <div class="imgbob__top_ads text-center">
       <div class="col-auto d-none d-md-flex">
        <!--<a href="https://codecanyon.net/item/imgbob-upload-and-share-images-platform/29964318" target="_blank"><img src="https://imgbob.com/ib/zqC2L2uw7n.png" width="100%"></a>-->
       </div>
       <div class="col-auto d-flex d-md-none">
        <!--<a href="https://codecanyon.net/item/imgbob-upload-and-share-images-platform/29964318" target="_blank"><img src="https://imgbob.com/ib/FNmZXIhvxM.png" width="100%"></a>-->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="imgbob-uploader-out" id="imgbob-uploader-out">
      <div id="imgbob-upload-clickable" class="imgbob-home-page-content imgbob-uploder-out-place">
       <div class="container-xl">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <div class="col-10">
          <div class="imgbob-home-text text-center">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="faa-bounce animated icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" /><path d="M7 18a4.6 4.4 0 0 1 0 -9a5 4.5 0 0 1 11 2h1a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7h-1" /><polyline points="9 15 12 12 15 15" /><line x1="12" y1="12" x2="12" y2="21" /></svg></span>
           <h2 class="imgbob-big-title">Upload and share your images.</h2>
           <p class="imgbob-description d-mobile-none">
            Drag and drop anywhere you want and start uploading your images now. 10 MB limit. (JPG, PNG, GIF) You can upload 5 images in one time.
           </p>
           <button id="imgbob-upload-clickable" class="imgbob-strat-uploading btn btn-primary">Start uploading</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <!-- <div class="bottom container">
      <div class="imgbob__bottom_ads text-center">
       <div class="col-auto d-none d-md-flex">
        <a href="https://codecanyon.net/item/imgbob-upload-and-share-images-platform/29964318" target="_blank"><img src="https://imgbob.com/ib/PpVZqxzBWh.png" width="100%"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-auto d-flex d-md-none">
        <a href="https://codecanyon.net/item/imgbob-upload-and-share-images-platform/29964318" target="_blank"><img src="https://imgbob.com/ib/FNmZXIhvxM.png" width="100%"></a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>-->
    </div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://imgbob.com/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://imgbob.com/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://imgbob.com/assets/libs/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://imgbob.com/assets/js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://imgbob.com/assets/libs/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://imgbob.com/assets/js/home/ibob.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?" async defer></script>
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-117141278-2"></script>
   <script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
     gtag('js', new Date());
     gtag('config', 'UA-117141278-2');
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```